# How can I make this substring extraction formula more efficient and easier to read?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

My formula's task is to extract the `Value` for the `Item Number Type` element in the following XML-like text:

```
<CustomField>
    <Name>Level of Concern</Name>
    <Value>N/A</Value>
</CustomField>
<CustomField>
    <Name>Item Number Type</Name>
    <Value>None</Value>
</CustomField>
```

"None" is the desired substring.
Brace yourself for a truly terrible formula:

```
=MID(D8, SEARCH("Item Number Type</Name><Value>", D8) + 30, 
    SEARCH("<", D8, SEARCH("Item Number Type</Name><Value>", D8) + 30)-
    (SEARCH("Item Number Type</Name><Value>", D8) + 30))
```

That formula works. Without variables (i.e. the ability to store the substring start index which is used 3 times) I don't know how to accomplish what I need in a cleaner, more efficient manner, do you?

Comment: Why not just use a temporary column and store that start index?  Seems like a small cost for much improved readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a recent Excel, you might be able to use `FILTERXML` to run an Xpath query.

You'll probably need make the XML-like text into valid XML by wrapping it in a root element as well.

Something like:

```
=FILTERXML("<root>" & D8 & "</root>", 
           "//CustomField[Name='Item Number Type']/Value/text()")
```

Comment: I was unable to make this work, I'm getting a #VALUE! error but I can see how it should work and it's cool.

Comment: @SteveK If you are unable to get it to work, why did you mark it as the answer?  That will inhibit others for providing solutions that might work for you.